# MySQL - alternative for like - regexp?

Tags: mysql, regex

i have got over one milion record in my database table.
When I use **like** is very slowly, when i use **match against** they lost some records.

I create help table:

**tag_list**

```
tag_id
tag_name
```

**tag_rel_message**

```
tag_id
messag_id
```

**messages**

```
message_id
message_text
```

in tag_list i add all words of $message_text - explode(" ", $message_text);

My new query is:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM tag_rel_messages trm 
INNER JOIN messages m ON (trm.message_id = m.message_id) 
INNER JOIN tag_list tl ON (trm.tag_id=tl.tag_id 
WHERE tl.tag_name REGEXP 'pionas' AND tl.tag_name REGEXP 'website' 
GROUP By trm.message_id
```

But not display any records.

What's wrong with this query?
Maybe i should use something other than REGEXP?

Thanks for help

Comment: if I understand you correctly, tag_list's `tag_name` contain only single token keywords, then how could any single token match both `pionas` and `website`?

Comment: Yes, exactly only single keywords. You're right. So what i should do to find only this message where all conditions are true?

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause states that `tag_name` needs to match both `'pionas'` **AND** `'website'`. Maybe try `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: Why `LIKE` and `REGEXP`? Why not `tag_name = 'pionas'` ?

Comment: I use a REGEXP because tag_name may be website, websites etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$words = array('pionas', 'website');
$tags_id = array();
foreach ($words as $key => $val) {
    $sql = "SELECT tag_id FROM tag_list WHERE tag_name LIKE '%".$val."%'";
    $records = $db->query($sql);
    $tags_id[$key] = array_column($records, "tag_id");
}

$inner_array = array();
foreach ($tags_id as $k => $v) {
    $short_name = "trm_".$k;
    $inner_array[] = " INNER JOIN tag_rel_message as ".$short_name." ON ( ".$short_name.".message_id = m.message_id AND ".$short_name.".tag_id IN (".implode(", ", $v).")) ";
}

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT m.* FROM messages m".implode(" ", $inner_array);
```

I think this is the same:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_text like '%pionas%' AND message_text like '%website%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how one column could match two things at the same time! You can use `OR` in place of `AND`, or you can use a single call to [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html).

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM tag_rel_messages trm 
INNER JOIN messages m ON (trm.message_id = m.message_id) 
INNER JOIN tag_list tl ON (trm.tag_id=tl.tag_id 
WHERE tl.tag_name REGEXP 'pionas|website' 
GROUP By trm.message_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join with the `tag_list` and `tag_rel_message` tables twice to match two different tags.

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages AS m
JOIN tag_rel_messages AS trm1 ON m.message_id = trm1.message_id
JOIN tag_list AS t1 ON t1.tag_id = trm1.tag_id
JOIN tag_rel_messages AS trm2 ON m.message_id = trm2.message_id
JOIN tag_list AS t2 on t2.tag_id = trm2.tag_id
WHERE t1.tag_name = 'pionas' AND t2.tag_name = 'website'
```

Another way to do it is to join with either tag, and count the number of results per message

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages AS m
JOIN tag_rel_messages AS trm ON m.message_id = trm.message_id
JOIN tag_list AS t ON t1.tag_id = trm.tag_id
WHERE t.tag_name IN ('pionas', 'website')
GROUP BY m.message_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

This second form is a little easier to generalize to any number of tags. Put all the tags in the `IN` clause, and change the `HAVING` clause to match the number of tags.